# How do I manage database evolutions when I'm using JPA?

Tags: mysql, jpa, playframework

I learned play by following the tutorial on their website for building a little blogging engine.

It uses JPA and in it's bootstrap calls Fixtures.Deletemodels(), (or something like that).

It basically nukes all the tables every time it runs and I lose all the data.

I've deployed a production system like (sans the nuke statement).

Now I need to deploy a large update to the production system. Lots of classes have changed, been added, and been removed. In my testing locally, without nuking the tables on every run I ran into sync issues. When I would try to write or read from tables play would throw errors. I opened up mysql and sure enough the tables had only been partially modified and modified incorrectly in some cases. Even if I have the DDL mode set to "create" in my config JPA can't seem to "figure out" how to reconcile the changes and modify my schema accordingly.

So I have to put back in the bootstrap statement that nukes all my tables.

So I started looking into database evolutions within Play and read an article on the play framework website about database evolutions. The article talked about version scripts, but it said, "If you work with JPA, Hibernate can handle database evolutions for you automatically. Evolutions are useful if you don’t use JPA".

So if JPA is supposed to be taking care of this for me, how do I deploy large updates to a large Play app? So far JPA has not been able to make the schema changes correctly and the app will throw errors. I'm not interested in losing all my data so the fix on dev "Fixtures.deleteModels()" can't really be used in prod.

Thanks in advance,
Josh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, JPA should not take care of it for you. It's not a magic tool. If you decide to rename the table "client" to "customer", the column "street" to "line1" and to switch the values of the customer type column from 1, 2, 3 to "bronze", "silver", "gold", there is no way for JPA to read in your mind and figure all the changes to do automagically.

To migrate from one schema to another, you use the same tools as if you didn't use JPA: SQL scripts, or more adavanced schema and data migration tools, or even custom migration JDBC code.

Comment: Ok, so the play documentation is simply wrong. This is a letdown as I really depended on this feature.

Comment: So can I enable evolution scripts while still using JPA? The play docs make it sound like the two are mutually exclusive.

Comment: What do you mean by "enable evolution scripts"?

Comment: Play framework's site has instructions on how to enable evolution scripts. you have to add a directory to your application and some other stuff. I haven't looked into it yet because their docs said you don't need it if you use JPA as JPA will manage your DB changes for you, (which I've now found to be a deceitful lie!).

Comment: As I said, JPA (and probably those evolution scripts) is able to transform an existing schema into a new one, by removing and creating columns and tables, but it won't migrate your data as you would like to migrate them. You'll have to program that.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [flyway](http://flywaydb.org). You may trigger database migrations from your code or maven.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called `hbm2ddl.auto=update` which will update your schema.
I would STRONGLY suggest to not use this setting in production as it introduces a whole new level of problems if something goes wrong.
It's perfectly fine for development though.

Comment: So how do I get my production schema all adjusted? The play website said that JPA would take care of it for me. Was this not correct?

Comment: Software development and system administration are two separate lands with their own rules, concerns and penalties. If you are willing to do things in production the way you use to do in development, you are asking for problems and loss of money! The point is: yes! you can have evolutions which eventually will be employed in production but do not run anything unless you have an experienced DBA supervising the work and concerned about what needs to be done in case things go very bad!

Answer (score 0):

When a JPA container starts (say, EclipseLink or any other), it expects to find a database which matches @Entity classes you've defined in your code. If the database has been migrated already, everything will work smoothly; otherwise: probably it will fail.

So, long story short, you need to perform database migrations (or evolutions, if you prefer) *before* the JPA container starts. Apparently, Play performs migrations for you, before Play kicks off the database manager you configured. So, in theory, regardless the ORM you are using, Play decides when it's time for the ORM to start its work. So, conceptually it should work.

For a good presentation about this subject, please have a look at the second video at: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/videos.html